# Reading in file contents rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a form that is attempting to read in a JSON file for parsing/actions/etc. I'm having problems getting it to read in the controller.

View:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => :admins, :action => :upload_json}, {:multipart => true, :method => :post}) do |f| %>

    <%= file_field_tag 'datafile' %>

<%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
```

Controller:

```
def upload_json

  file_data = params[:datafile]

  File.read(file_data) do |file|

     file.each do |line|
       ## does stuff here....
     end
  end

end
```

A similar function works in my `seed.rb` file when I'm seeding data - just can't get it to read in an uploaded file.

The error I'm getting is: `can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String`.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to change:

```
file_data = params[:datafile]
```

to

```
file_data = params[:datafile].tempfile
```

And decided to use the `.open` function to change:

```
File.read(file_data) do |file|
```

to

```
File.open(file_data, 'r') do |file|
```

Comment: For clarity, it's the `.tempfile` method which resolves the `can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String` error (not the change to `File.open`).

Comment: @Mike For further clarity, using `File.read` does not get you the line-by-line processing that you want. Use `File.open`.

Answer (score 2):

params[:datafile] is an instance of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile class with tempfile attached with that.To open the tempfile

You try something like

```
File.open(params[:datafile].path) do |file|
 #your stuff goes here
end
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Open the uploaded file using `path`.

`params[:datafile]` is an instance of [`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) class and you'll need to get at the stored file by calling `path` to properly process it.

Additionally, `File.read` will not get you the line-by-line processing you're looking for. You need to change that to `File.open`.

Try this:

**Controller**

```
def upload_json

  uploaded_datafile = params[:datafile]

  File.open( uploaded_datafile.path ) do |file|

     file.each_line do |line|

       # Do something with each line.

     end

  end

end
```

#### Alternative Style

```
def upload_json

  File.foreach( params[:datafile].path ) do |line|

    # Do something with each line.

  end 

  # FYI: The above method block returns `nil` when everything goes okay.

end
```