# ruby on rails 5 server-side CSV validation ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

In my lib/csv_validation.rb file I got my validate method:

```
def self.validate(file, delimiter, columns)
  return false unless File.exist?(file)
  content = File.read(file, encoding: 'utf-8')
  return false unless content.valid_encoding?
  content.each_line do |line|
    return false if line.count(delimiter) < columns - 1
  end
  true
end
```

when I send a CSV file via ajax post request I get the following error:

```
Started POST "/students/import" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-20 01:03:43 +0100
Processing by StudentsController#import as */*
Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd0a228ca38 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20171220-4516-or6qi3.csv>, @original_filename="students_fail.csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"students_fail.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



TypeError (can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to IO (ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile#to_io gives Tempfile)):

app/models/student.rb:114:in `exist?'
app/models/student.rb:114:in `import'
app/controllers/students_controller.rb:50:in `import'
Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb
Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb (0.4ms)
Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb
Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.4ms)
Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (14.4ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Accessing mime types via constants is deprecated. Please change `Mime::HTML` to `Mime[:html]`. (called from acceptable_content_type? at /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:58)
```

I was searching for `can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to IO` but I just find something like `can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String`.

I am not sure how to handle this error or where I can find someone with the same problem.

sorry for my bad english and thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile#tempfile` method.

Documented [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionDispatch%2FHttp%2FUploadedFile:tempfile).

So you can call it like this:

`File.read(file.tempfile, encoding: 'utf-8')`

That will allow the object to transform to an actual file as opposed to an `ActionDispatch` object.

See this SO Article: [Reading in file contents rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589973/reading-in-file-contents-rails)